# String manipulation in shell

Tags: shell, shell-script

I was writing a shell script to generate a string in a particular format so that it can be used as a input in one of the XML I am working with.

Given a input file in the format `<attribute field>,<data_type>,<size>`

```
instanceid,varchar,256
sysdate,date
status,number
notes,varchar,4000
created_on,date
```

I want to store in a variable the "check sum" like `md5( INSTANCEID || STATUS || NOTES)`. That is I want all the attribute fields except the field having date as it's type Or'd.

The script I had written is this

```
IFS=$'\n'
file=$(cat source.txt)
line_number=$(cat source.txt | wc -l)
checksum="md5( "
for line in $file
do
let line_number=line_number-1
data_field=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d','| tr "a-z" "A-Z")
data_type=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d',' | tr "a-z" "A-Z")
if [ $data_type != "DATE" ]  && [ $line_number -gt 0 ]
  then checksum+="$data_field || "
elif [ $data_type != "DATE" ] && [ $line_number -eq 0 ]
  then checksum+=" $data_field "
fi
done
checksum+=")"
echo $checksum
```

This script works fine with all the input scenarios except when the last line has a attribute with date as it's type.

In which case the variable has a value like`md5( INSTANCEID || STATUS || NOTES || )`

I tried to check if the last line was a date using `tail` command, but this again would fail if the last few lines had it's type as date.

How can I do away with the `||` which appears in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is `checksum="${checksum% || })"` instead of `checksum+=")"`. Just unconditionally add the `||` string in each step and then strip off the last unnecessary one at the very end (so the `line_number` computation is no longer needed).

A better way to do this is

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { printf "md5( " } 
         toupper($2) != "DATE" { printf "%s%s", sep, toupper($1); sep = " || " }
         END { print ")" }' source.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

- It’s remarkable how rarely `cat` is useful in a shell script. 
  `$(cat source.txt | wc -l)` is a classic [useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat);
  if you needed to count the lines in a file,
  `$(wc -l < source.txt)` is a much cleaner ways of doing it.
- But you don’t need to count the lines in `source.txt`.
- `file=$(cat source.txt)` is an ugly way to read a file;

  ```
  while read …
  do
      ︙
  done < filename
  ```

  is better. 
  `read` has the benefit that it can split lines into fields for you.
- It’s silly to run `tr` twice for each line of the file
  when you need only to run it once on the entire file. 
  In some situations,

  ```
  tr … < filename | while read …
  do
      ︙
  done
  ```

  works nicely. 
  But there’s a problem with this: the `while` loop runs in a subshell,
  so changes that you make to shell variables (e.g., `checksum`)
  won’t be visible after the loop ends. 
  Terdon shows one way to work around that problem; here’s another one:

  ```
  tr … < filename | { while read …
  do
          ︙
      commands that potentially change checksum.
          ︙
  done
      ︙
  commands that use $checksum.
      ︙
  }
  ```
- As you’ve discovered,
  identifying the last occurrence of something can be difficult. 
  It’s often easier to identify the first:

  ```
  checksum="md5("
  first=1
  tr "a-z" "A-Z" < source.txt | { while IFS=, read data_field data_type size
  do
      if [ "$data_type" != "DATE" ]
      then
          if [ "$first" ]
          then
              first=
          else
              checksum+=" || "
          fi
          checksum+="$data_field"
      fi
  done
  checksum+=")"
  echo "$checksum"
  }
  ```

  Note that you *really* don’t need to test
  `if [ "$data_type" != "DATE" ]` twice.
  Also note that you should always quote references to shell variables
  (e.g., `"$data_type"`) unless you have a good reason not to
  and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.
- As a further optimization,
  you can eliminate the `first` variable and simply use `checksum` itself
  to identify your first iteration through the loop:

  ```
  checksum=
  tr "a-z" "A-Z" < source.txt | { while IFS=, read data_field data_type size
  do
      if [ "$data_type" != "DATE" ]
      then
          if [ "$checksum" != "" ]
          then
              checksum+=" || "
          fi
          checksum+="$data_field"
      fi
  done
  checksum="md5($checksum)"
  echo "$checksum"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything half as complicated as what you've written. You could just do:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

checksum="md5("
## Read each line into the fields array (read -a fields), with fields
## separated by commas (IFS=,)
while IFS=, read -a fields
do
    ## If the 2nd element of the array is not "DATE"
    if [ ${fields[1]} != "DATE" ]
    then
        ## Add this to $checksum
        checksum+="${fields[0]} || "
    fi
## The tr is making everything upper case and then feeds
## directly into the while loop.
done < <(tr "a-z" "A-Z" < "$1")
## Get rid of the last || and add the closing ")"
checksum="${checksum% || })"
printf "OUT is: %s\n" "$checksum"
```

You then run the script with your file as input:

```
$ foo.sh file
OUT is: md5(INSTANCEID || STATUS || NOTES)
```

Comment: (1) “The script you posted only stores the details of the first line of input.”  Huh?  `file=$(cat source.txt)` reads the entire file, and `for line in $file` loops through the lines.  (2) I’m shocked that `< "$@"` isn’t a syntax error.  If there are two or more parameters, it is equivalent to `< "$*"`.

Comment: @G-Man 1) yes, I had originally misunderstood the requirements. That sentence was left over from my first draft of the answer, thanks for pointing it out. 2) You're absolutely right, I don't know what  I was thinking. Fixed now.